# Labeled unique contours (or draw independient contours)

Tags: python, opencv, label

Im working in python and opencv library.

I can threshold a camera capture, find contours (more than one) and draw. 
But I have a problem. I try to identify those contours with an unique id or tag. (for example: Id: 1 , Id:2) to track them.
I need this contours use a persistent id.

The goal is draw a line and count more than one contour and sometimes more than one near contours converts in a big one.

Note: Im working with a depth camera and my image its an array of depth.

add a piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

```
    countours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(countours) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid

        for (i,c) in enumerate(countours):
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)

            M = cv2.moments(c)
            if M["m00"] > 0:
                center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
                centerString = str(center)
                x = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]))
                y = (int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
            else:
                center = int(x), int(y)




            if radius > 10:
                # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                           (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                # then update the ponter trail
                if self.previous_position:
                    cv2.line(self.trail, self.previous_position, center,
                             (255, 255, 255), 2)
                    cv2.add(self.trail, frame, frame)
                    print center
    self.previous_position = center
    if len(countours) < 1:
        center = 0
        self.trail = numpy.zeros((self.cam_height, self.cam_width, 3),
                             numpy.uint8)
        self.previous_position = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options. First off, the contours are already in a Python list, so the indices of that list can be used to enumerate them. In fact you're already doing that in some sense with `(i,c) in enumerate(countours)`. You can just use the index `i` to 'color' each contour with the value `i` drawing on a blank image, and then you'll know which contour is which just by examining the image. The other, probably better option IMO, is to use [`cv2.connectedComponents()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents) to label the binary images instead of the contours of the binary image. Also pre-labeling you might try [morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to close up blobs.

Comment: @A.Garrido if it answered your question, you can mark the answer as accepted. However if you try one of these approaches and you have any trouble implementing them, I can expand on it!

Comment: your first answer solve to find and label contours, but now, labels depends of width and change (0 is for highest value of width, top image, and 1 is lower value), and changes frame by frame depending the position. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I follow your recommendation and I have new problems :)

Label is not persistent. When I move both contours, numbers of labels change.
Add some pictures and my code.

[Hand label 0 and circle 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGT41.png)

[Hand label 1 and circle 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2tzt.png)

```
while True:

    cnt += 1
    if (cnt % 10) == 0:
        now = time.time()
        dt = now - last
        fps = 10/dt
        fps_smooth = (fps_smooth * smoothing) + (fps * (1.0-smoothing))
        last = now

    c = dev.color

    cad = dev.cad

    dev.wait_for_frames()

    c = cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    depth = dev.depth * dev.depth_scale * 1000

    print depth

    #d = cv2.applyColorMap(depth.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLORMAP_SUMMER)



    print depth


    res = np.float32(dev.depth)

    depth = 255 * np.logical_and(depth >= 100, depth <= 500)
    res2 = depth.astype(np.uint8)

    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    #res2 = cv2.blur(res2,(15,15))
    res2 = cv2.erode(res2, kernel, iterations=4)
    res2 = cv2.dilate(res2, kernel, iterations=8)

    im_floodfill = res2.copy()

    h, w = res2.shape[:2]
    mask2 = np.zeros((h + 2, w + 2), np.uint8)

    cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask2, (0, 0), 255)

    im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)

    im_out = res2 | im_floodfill_inv

    im_out = cv2.blur(im_out,(5,5))

    label = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(im_out)

    n = label[0] - 1
    cog = np.delete(label[3], 0, 0)

    for i in xrange(n):
        # im = cv2.circle(im,(int(cog[i][0]),int(cog[i][1])), 10, (0,0,255), -1)
        cv2.putText(im_out, str(i), (int(cog[i][0]), int(cog[i][1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("Depth", res)

    cv2.imshow("OUT", im_out)

    cv2.imshow( "C", res2)
```